# Using Samsung Galazy SIII / S3 debugging mode (AVD)

Tags: android, mobile

I'm trying to install an android application I'm writing on my S3. I've downloaded the USB drivers, the device is being recognised fine. I have USB Debugging enabled, yet when I connect the device nothing shows up in the AVD manager. Am I missing something? I've tried changing the USB connection type between MTP and PTP but it doesn't make any difference.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean what you have written. The Android Virtual Device Manager (AVD) does what it says, and since your S3 ain't virtual it won't show up. You'll get to see it when you try running or debugging it in Eclipse's Android Device Chooser. Could you clarify if it's that what you mean or you simply looked at the wrong place?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to populate the `android_winusb.inf` file with your device's ID (in {android-sdk}/extras/google/usb_driver). 
You also need to have the 'Google USB driver' installed in the SDK manager.

1. Find the device's ID in Windows device manager, right click on your USB device, then go to properties, and Details tab, there should be something like 'Device ID number':
2. Add it to the android_winusb.inf (in the '[Google.NTx86]' section):

   [Google.NTx86]

   %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_681C

   %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_681C&MI_03

Comment: What do I need to add to the inf file exactly? I already have the Google USB driver installed. Thanks